# How to add a matrix to itself in an iterative way?

Tags: python

I have a code which looks like:

```
X = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]


result = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]

Final = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]



for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(X)):
        for x in range(4):
                    result[i][j] = X[i][j] + X[i][j]
                    Final[i][j]=result[i][j]+X[i][j]


for r in Final: 
    print(r)
```

I want to add X matrix with itself for 4 times and return the answer as the final summed matrix. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: You need to write some code. Write the worst, most horrible code you can. You have permission. Then improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) function to generate pairs from the list, and then iterate over those pairs to print your messages:

```
l = [5, 6, 7, 8]
for source, dest in zip(l, l[1:]):
    print('Source = {}'.format(source))
    print('Destination = {}'.format(dest))
```

Output:

```
Source = 5
Destination = 6
Source = 6
Destination = 7
Source = 7
Destination = 8
```

The key here is the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) function which works by combining each item with its successor in the list:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l[1:]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> zip(l, l[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

And if the list is not even in length, the last item will be dropped:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> zip(l, l[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what i was looking for. :) @mhawke

Comment: @UjjalShaha: no problem. I don't get why your question was closed - it seemed pretty specific to me, but you got an answer anyway :)

Comment: Hey i need some help. Seems like Stack Overflow won't let me ask any more questions. :/ Is there any way to contact you?

Answer (score 1):

```
yourlist = [5,6,7,8]
for i in range(len(yourlist)-1):
    print "Source: " + str(yourlist[i])
    print "Destination: " + str(yourlist[i+1]) + "\n"
```

Output:

```
Source = 5  
Destination = 6

Source = 6  
Destination = 7

Source = 7  
Destination = 8
```